# how to make separate field in wordpress user_data_

Tags: php, functions

I am using wordpress membership site with s2members plugin. 
I added 4 custom field in registration form with s2member
But I want to use that custom field outside of wordpress with php

**following command work perfectly it give me data also but in one field and I want separate field data** following is all example

**PHP command**
get_user_meta($current_user->ID,"Tw941I8fXg_s2member_custom_fields",true);
 var_dump($user_info);

**Results** 
string(92) "a:3:{s:8:"mobileno";s:10:"xxxxxxxxxx";s:4:"city";s:6:"XXXXXXX";s:8:"cocode";s:7:"99999999";}"

**Need result like**
$mobileno = "XXXXXXXXXX"
$city ="XXXXXXXX"
$cocode = "XXXXXXX"

Please Note :
I can count and find contain within results but don't know how to take variable 
here S:10,S:4,S:8 command are same in all members field

Answer (score 1):

This is the serialized string. You need to unserialize it:

```
$raw = get_user_meta($current_user->ID,"Tw941I8fXg_s2member_custom_fields",true);
$data = maybe_unserialize($raw);
extract($data);
```

Now, $data will have an array of all options, and the extract will turn each element into a variable with a value.